# Steps to run Test framework in Docker and Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, ui-automation

Background:
I am a newbie to docker.

I have 2 automation frameworks in my local PC - One for Mobile and other a web application. I have integrated the test frameworks with Jenkins.
Both test frameworks have open Jar dependencies mentioned in Maven pom.xml.
Now i want that when I click on Jenkins Job run to execute tests, my tests should run in a docker container.

Can anyone please give me steps to

1. Configure Docker in this completer Integrated framework
2. How to push my dependencies in docker
3. How to integrate jenkins and Docker
4. how to run Tests of web and mobile apps in docker on jenkins job click

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Jenkins professional, but from my experience, there are many possible setups here:

Assumptions:

1. By "Automation Framework", I understand that there is some java module (built by maven, I believe for gradle it will be pretty much the same) that has some tests that in turn call various APIs that should exist "remotely". It can be HTTP calls, working with selenium servers and so forth.
2. Currently, your Jenkins job looks like this (it doesn't really matter whether its an "old-school" job "step-by-step" definition or groovy script (pipelines):

   - Checkout from GIT
   - run `mvn test`
   - publish test results

If so, you need to prepare a docker image that will run your test suite (preferably with maven) to take advantage of surefire reports.

So you'll need to build this docker image once (see `docker build` command) and make it available in the private repository / docker hub depending on what your organization prefers. Technically for this docker image, you can consider a Java image as a base image, get the maven (download and unzip + configure) then issue the "git pull command". You might want to pass credentials as system variables to the docker process itself (see '-e' flag)
The main point here is that maven **inside the docker image** will run the build, so it will resolve the dependencies automatically (you might want to configure custom repositories if you have them in `settings.xml` of maven). This effectively answers the second question.

One subtle point is results that should be somehow shown in Jenkins:
You might want to share the volume with `surefire-results` folder with the Jenkins "host machine" so that Jenkins's plugins that are supposed to show the results of tests will work. The same idea is applicable if you're using something like allure reports, spock reports and so forth.

Now when the image is ready the integration with Jenkins might be as simple as running a `docker run` command and wait till it's done. So now the Jenkins job will look like:

```
 docker run pre-defined image -e <credentials for git>
 show reports
```

This is one example of possible integration.

One slightly different option is running docker build as a job definition. This might be beneficial if for each build that image should be significantly different but it will make the build slower.

Comment: Can you please paste any Github link if you have any with the docker file with all dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Following approach can be followed to achieve your goal

1. Create a docker file with all your setup as well as dependency ( [refer](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/))
2. Install docker plugin on jenkins to integrate the support of docker ([refer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin))
3. Use Jenkinsfile's approach to pull the docker image or create it by dockerfile and run the test within docker.

> below sample code just for reference

```
node 
{
  checkout scm
  docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example.com', 'credentials-id') 
  {
    def customImage = docker.build("my-image")
    docker.image('my-image').inside 
    {
        //Run inside the container
        sh 'run test'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ,Where should the above docker file be placed ?is it the same test repo ?

Comment: Hi, Where should i include the above docker file? In the project repo in github?

Comment: Yes, its always better to keep it in the same repo as your test.

Comment: Can you please paste any Github link if you have any with the docker file with all dependencies?

Comment: Dockerfile has to be created by you by understanding what framework you are using and what dependencies needed, https://github.com/ypasmk/robot-framework-docker refer this is sample for robot framework you can refer to understand.